# New-PSSession : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Tags: powershell

I am running the following powershell command that works just fine if I run it from the machine itself.  I am logging in as the same user that the continuous integration server runs with, but I get the following error from the CI Server:

```
New-PSSession : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 
[18:19:47][Step 1/1] 'stage-web-01'.
[18:19:47][Step 1/1] At line:1 char:13
[18:19:47][Step 1/1] + $Sessions = New-PSSession –ComputerName $Servers
[18:19:47][Step 1/1] +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[18:19:47][Step 1/1]     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-PSSession], ParameterB 
[18:19:47][Step 1/1]    indingException
[18:19:47][Step 1/1]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell 
[18:19:47][Step 1/1]    .Commands.NewPSSessionCommand
```

Any thoughts on what I need to do differently from the CI Server? I checked and I'm running the same version locally as I am on the CI server.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your exact problem, but I ran into a similar problem, and turns out I had the character '–' and not '-' when I called parameters.

Wrong:

```
New-PSSession –ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionUri 'http://MYSERVER/PowerShell/' -credential $Credential
```

Right

```
New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'http://MYSERVER/PowerShell/' -credential $Credential
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the Script execution mode -- I had to set it to be "Execute with "-File" argument.